# How to use gsub to simplify regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I would like to escape the `#` with `\` when they appear in `\href` commands.

Normally I would write a regex such as `s/(\\href\{.*?)#(.*?)\}/\1\\#\2/g`, but I imagine `gsub` would we a good choice here to first extract the `\href` content and then replace `#` with `\#`.

```
Here is some text with a \href{./file.pdf#section.1.5}{link} to section 1.5.
```

There can be multiple links in one line.

**Question**

Can `gsub` simplify these sorts of problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except if one or several of the urls contained inside `\href{..}`s has a password part enclosed between quotes like `http://username:"sdkfj#lkn#"@domainname.org/path/file.ext`, the only possible place for the character `#` in a url is at the end and delimits the fragment part: `./path/path/file.rb?val=toto#thefragmentpart`.

In other words, if I am not wrong there's max one `#` to escape per `href{...}`. Then you can simply do that:

```
text.gsub(/\\href{[^#}]*\K#/, "\\#")
```

The character class `[^#}]` forbids the character `}` and ensures that you are always between curly brackets.

Answer (score 3):

You could use two gsubs : one with an argument and a block (for `href{...}`), one with 2 arguments (to replace `#` with `\#`):

```
text = %q(Here is some text with a \href{./file.pdf#section.1.5}{link} to section 1.5.)
puts text.gsub(/href{[^}]+}/){ |href| href.gsub('#', '\#') }
#=> Here is some text with a \href{./file.pdf\#section.1.5}{link} to section 1.5.
```

If you want to launch it from a terminal with `ruby -e` for a `test.txt` file, you can use:

```
ruby -pe '$_.gsub(/href{[^}]+}/){ |href| href.gsub(%q|#|, %q|\#|) }' test.txt
# Here is some text with a \href{./file.pdf#section.1.5}{link} to section 1.5.
# Here is some text with a \href{./file.pdf#section.1.6}{link} to section 1.6.
# Here is some text with a \href{./file.pdf#section.1.7}{link} to section 1.7.
```

or

```
ruby -e 'puts ARGF.read.gsub(/href{[^}]+}/){ |href| href.gsub(%q|#|, %q|\#|) }' test.txt
# Here is some text with a \href{./file.pdf#section.1.5}{link} to section 1.5.
# Here is some text with a \href{./file.pdf#section.1.6}{link} to section 1.6.
# Here is some text with a \href{./file.pdf#section.1.7}{link} to section 1.7.
```

Do not mix `ruby -pe` and `ARGF.read`, it would only read the first line of your file!

Comment: If I do `ruby -0777 -pe 'ARGF.read.gsub(/href{[^}]+}/){ |href| href.gsub(%q|#|, %q|\#|) }' test.txt` then it  works for the first link, but not the remaining. What am I doing wrong?